# Jfrog Xray: Violation shows fix version, but still reports as violation

Tags: jfrog-xray

I recently upgraded our docker image to the fix version shown for:

```
Upgrade To:

 8:sqlite-libs - 0:3.26.0-18.el8_8
```

And the component shows the correct version

```
Impacted Component: rpm://8:sqlite-libs:0:3.26.0-18.el8_8
```

But the violation still shows in the UI. Is this due to the:

```
Vulnerable Versions:

 8:sqlite-libs - All Versions
```

If so I will go about adding to ignore list.

I am expecting this  to not show up in violations since I have the correct upgrade version.

Comment: There are multiple vulnerabilities related sqlite-libs which affects All Versions. Violations will be generated for those if policy criteria matches for the vulnerabilities, in such case, you can use ignore rules accordingly. Add more information if it is reporting for any specific CVE which was fixed already.